# Is there an analogue of Evaluated->False (in FindRoot) for FindMinimum?

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization

I guess functions like `FindRoot`, `FindMinimum`, etc puts the estimation number into the expression, and then do other calculations. Concerning the step of substitution, there are two ways: one is to first substitute, then evaluate the expression, the other is the opposite. It seems that Mathematica chooses the latter method by default(always try to simplify or at least evaluate the expression). But this can cause some problems. For example, I have

`f[y_] := (Values@FindRoot[y + p == 3 p, {p, 2}])[[1]];`

If I excuse these code:

`FindRoot[f[x] == 6, {x, 0}]`

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-4.+x} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {p} = {2.}. >>

Luckily there is an `Evaluated->False`option in `FindRoot`, which can solve the problem.

```
FindRoot[f[x] == 6, {x, 0}, Evaluated -> False]
(*{x -> 12.}*)
```

However, functions like `FindMinimum` does not have such an option.

```
FindMinimum[f[x]^2 + f[x], {x, 0}]
```

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-4.+x} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {p} = {2.}. >>

I know that if I change my definition of `f[y_]` to `f[y_?NumericQ]` can get the result, this also works for `FindRoot`; but I am just curious about whether the solution similar to `Evaluated->False` option exist, i.e., a solution that prevents the expression from being evaluated before substitution.

Extras: the expected results with symbolic functions

```
g[y_] := (Values@Solve[y + p == 3 p, p])[[1, 1]]
FindRoot[g[x] == 6, {x, 0}]
(*{x -> 12.}*)
FindMinimum[g[x]^2 + g[x], {x, 0}]
(*{-0.25, {x -> -1.}}*)
```